# О погоде и прогнозах. Прослезятся дожди

Tags: грамотная-речь, жаргон

Насколько правильны и уместны такие выражения:

*Кое-где прослезятся дожди*,

*В Сочи и Геленджике по 25 градусов*?

Answer (score 2):

1. В выражении "прослезятся дожди" для меня странно звучит выбранный *источник* слёз - он отождествлён с *процессом* испускания слёз (дождём): как бы "**поток слёз прослезился**"; вполне нормально было бы "небеса прослезятся" (дождями). Ирония такого выражения уместна, если перед этим в новостях не было траурных сообщений.
2. Во втором выражении мешает предлог "**по**": он соответствует рапределению имеющегося количества градусов между получателями, будто "из мешка": каждому выдано по столько-то. На самом же деле, условно говоря, не *раздаются* разные градусы, а *приписываются* одни и те же, которые от этого "в мешке" не убывают. С другой стороны, это не так страшно, поскольку устоялись выражения типа "каждому дали по 10 лет условно". Но смысл нашего выражения в том, что в разных местах "погода одна и та же", а не "две одинаковых погоды".

Comment: «Смысл нашего выражения в том, что в разных местах "погода одна и та же"», но ведь именно о погоде и не сказано, лишь о градусах. А это означает, что включение ПО только усложняет формулирование подробностей, которые далее нормальный прогноз дать обязан.

Comment: Тысячу извинений, но верным и удовлетворительным этот ответ Alex_ander я не помечал, хотя он и полный и обстоятельный. Не знаю в чём дело, но пусть так и будет.

Answer (score 1):

*Кое-где прослезятся дожди* - это вопрос о том, насколько уместно поэтическое выражение в прогнозе погоды? Не нам решать. Само сочетание "прослезятся дожди" ничем кроме стилистической особенности глаз и ухо не царапает.

*В Сочи и Геленджике по 25 градусов?* - предлог не нужен. Но тоже ничего не нарушает.

Comment: Второй я бы все-таки пометил как разговорный. *И в Сочи, и в Геленджике 25 градусов* - нейтральный. Слезящиеся дожди как-то тоже не звучит в нейтральной речи: слишком романтично, поэтично (и, по моему мнению, пошло-слащаво).

Answer (score 1):

Дождь - это атмосферные осадки, выпадающие из облаков в виде капель воды? Отнюдь нет, **дождь - это вещь в себе,** неиссякаемый предмет вдохновения для поэтов всех времен.

Сначала была **вполне понятная метафора**: "**плакала осень** слезами холодными" или "**прослезилась осень** грустью и дождями".

Потом **метафора усложнилась**, теперь уже "**дождик слёзы льёт и льёт** Целый вечер напролёт, Плачет, не переставая  он". А когда плачущий дождь перестал кого-либо удивлять, поэты стали находить новые смелые образы: "**Прослезились дожди** на сиреневых улицах, Туман-хулиган свой косяк раскурил".

Дошла поэзия и **до прогноза погоды**, и это совсем не странно. Чтобы тебя слушали, нужно удивлять, надо быть раскованным и свободным (где это позволяется, конечно, и соответствует общему непринужденному стилю).

Comment: Насчёт хулигана тоже помню: Москвичей можем успокоить, это — не туман, а капли воды в воздухе. Не соглашусь в части непринуждённости: она приходит от знания предмета и языка. Эфирные юноши и девушки иметь этого не могут, считывать с листа для них труд.

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу проблем. Прогноз погоды - не военная сводка. Можно и немного повольничать в стилистике.

Comment: — В Сочи и Геленджике по 25 градусов? - предлог не нужен, — пишет behemothus. Ненужный предлог... Может на нужное чернила употреблять? Помните из Горина: «Сделаешь иногда что-то ненужное, потом самому же хуже».

Comment: Не понял вас. .....

Comment: «Немного повольничать» превратилось за 25 лет в вольницу.